How to characterize this condition for commutative squares in $\Delta$
In the simplex category $\Delta$ we have the situation, that

pullbacks exist for cospans $[a] \xrightarrow{\alpha} [n] \xleftarrow{\beta} [b]$ in $\Delta_\text{mono}$ and
pushouts exist spans $[a] \xleftarrow{\alpha} [n] \xrightarrow{\beta} [b]$ in $\Delta_{epi}$.

Now, given a pullback $[k] = [a] \times_{[n]} [b]$ of $[a] \xrightarrow{\alpha} [n] \xleftarrow{\beta} [b]$ in $\Delta_\text{mono}$, there is also a pushout $[a] \sqcup_{[k]} [b]$ of the resulting span $[a] \xleftarrow{f_a} [k] \xrightarrow{f_b} [b]$, but only relative to $[n]$ in the sense that it is the smallest face $\delta:[a] \sqcup_{[k]} [b] \to [n]$ making the square (of mono's) commute.


We say that a commuting square in $\Delta_\text{mono}$ is relative mono-bicartesian if it is a pullback diagram and the relative pushout satisfies $\delta = \text{id}$.

Now, the situation in $\Delta_\text{epi}$ is completely dual, giving rise to the following definition:

We say that a commuting square in $\Delta_\text{epi}$ is relative epi-bicartesian if it is a pushout diagram and the relative pullback satisfies $\sigma = \text{id}$.

Now, I would like to put both conditions together for general commuting squares in $\Delta$:

On the left hand side we have an arbitrary commuting square. It is always possible to decompose it as I did on the right. Here, I used that a morphism $\gamma$ has a unique epi-mono factorization $\gamma= \delta_{\gamma} \circ \sigma_{\gamma}.$

We say that a commuting square in $\Delta$ is relative bicartesian if $\delta = \text{id}$ and $\sigma = \text{id}$.

In particular, a relative bicartesian square subdivides into four squares where the upper is relative epi-bicartesian and the lower is relative mono-bicartesian.
Now, as you may have noticed this seems all pretty artificial and technical. My questions are therefore:

Do you see an easier/slicker way to characterize relative bicartesian squares in $\Delta$?
Can these conditions be found in the literature and if so, where?

Why do I care? Well, ugly or not, these relative bicartesian squares in $\Delta$ model pretty accurately the (degenerate and non-degenerate) $k$-dimensional faces of the $n$-cube $\Box^n$. These faces are indexed by the sides $[a]$ and $[b]$ (satisfying $a+b = n+k$) of the square, ultimately giving rise to a double complex (similar to the Moore complex of $\mathbb{Z}\Delta^n$).

Edit: My secret hope is that $a+b=n+k$ is actually a necessary and sufficient condition for a commutative square (see image) to be relative bicartesian.
Given that this is true I would still like to rephrase this condition in a more category theoretic way.

Edit: For the record, I seems natural to work in the arrow category of $\Delta$ and require morphisms to preserve the degree of an arrow: $\deg\left( [k] \rightarrow [n] \right)=n-k.$ Still I need to check the claim from the previous edit.

Last edit: It's true. Still I am happy for comments/alternative answers/literature suggestions.

I suppose you're actually working in the augmented simplex category? Intersections of monos in $\Delta$ can be empty...
